# Looking for a typeclass where category objects are partially consumable (chemical engineering)

Tags: haskell, logic, typeclass, category-theory

**Question**

I'm looking to describe processes in chemical engineering that that transmute some substances into others. Is there a category that describes morphisms that consume "substances"?

**Examples of what I would like to model**

To give some examples:

A transformation mix that combines two substances into a mixture.

A transformation boil that boils a substance into some byproducts.

A transformation split that separates a substance to be used in 2 different processes according to a pre-defined proportion.

And so on...

**Not a function**

As you can see, each chemical process is not merely a function, since its goal is not to "compute" a value but to translate some amounts of certain substances into others.

**Maybe a Category?**

This led me to consider categories which generalize the notion of functions.

class Category cat where
-- | the identity morphism
id :: cat a a

```
-- | morphism composition
(.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c
```

Conceptually this works since chemical processes are composable exactly in this way.

More specific Category

I know there are more specific instances of categories that encode more abstractions (e.g., Cartesian categories). A Cartesian category introduces products:

```hs
instance PreCartesian Hask (,) where
    fst = Prelude.fst
    snd = Prelude.snd
    diag a = (a,a)
    (f &&& g) a = (f a, g a)

-- alias
class (Monoidal k p i, PreCartesian k p) => Cartesian k p i | k -> p i 
instance (Monoidal k p i, PreCartesian k p) => Cartesian k p i
```

However, there is an issue. Conceptually, morphisms in Cartesian categories "compute with" rather than "consume" their objects. From the function diag a = (a, a) you can see that it's able to duplicate the object (this is not be possible in chemical engineering).

It seems like most category typeclasses deal with "computation" rather than "consumption".

**Consumable Categories?**

Are there any categories which describe morphisms that consume their objects? Any useful implementations in Haskell or research papers that I could look for?

**Linear logic**

Using Curry-Howard, perhaps it's easier to find an equivalent logic first and then map to the category. I stumbled on linear logic which seems to help:

[more about linear logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW5T5.png)

Comment: You might enjoy Google's search results for "located process calculus for chemical reactions". There's lots of prior art there.

Comment: From the categorical point of view, you might be interested in Petri nets. John Baez did some work on chemistry using those.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a nice application of Linear Haskell! GHC 9.0 and newer supports the `LinearHaskell`, which enable linear functions.

Comment: An example typeclass definition for a category isomorphic to linear logic I guess is the goal here - whether or not it needs to use `LinearHaskell`. My suspicion is that LinearHaskell isn't necessary to define a typeclass isomorphic to linear logic.

Comment: @idomorphism If you want to represent linear logic at a type-level, in the sense of CH, you will need the `LinearTypes` extension. The reason that extension exists is because it is otherwise not possible to have linear types in the Haskell type system. Although, I'm not fully sure I know what you mean by "a typeclass isomorphic to linear logic." Maybe you can clarify that a bit more?

Comment: @DavidYoung that makes sense, thanks. I mean the typeclass that represents the category that is isomorphic to linear logic. In the same way that `Control.Category` typeclasses represent certain simple categories which are isomorphic to certain simpler logics.

Comment: I guess what you are saying is that this typeclass will inevitably have to use linear haskell in its type definitions. Because these types will necessarily be propositions in linear logic.

Answer (score 2):

There’s certainly prior art in [the use of linear logic for reaction modelling](https://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/%7Ekyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1096-6.pdf).

If multiple reactants can combine, maybe what you’re looking for is an operad, rather than a category.

Is there any particular reason why [multisets](https://github.com/runarorama/mset) don’t suffice as a basic representation?

Comment: The main benefit is that tools like linear logic can help typecheck if all reactants are properly consumed, prevents multiple-consumption, allows suspending choices through A & B, etc. In general I'm looking for the most specific mathematical structure that models my domain to inherit the most tooling.

Answer (score 2):

Your `PreCartesian` class is too strong. The class you actually want should abstract only a [symmetric monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_monoidal_category)

```
class Category k where   id :: k a a
                         (.) :: k b c -> k a b -> k a c
class=>Monoidal k where  attachUnit :: k a (a,())
                         detachUnit :: k (a,()) a
                         regroup :: k (a, (b, c)) ((a, b), c)
                         regroup' :: k ((a, b), c) (a, (b, c))
                         (***) :: k a b -> k α β -> k (a,α) (b,β)
class=>Symmetric k where swap :: k (a,b) (b,a)
```

`attachUnit`...`regroup'` are boilerplates, needed because Haskell's `(,)`/`()` isn't really a monoid.

Alternatively the class could be called `Braided`, which would also have `swap`. The difference is that a symmetric category demands `swap . swap ≡ id`, which does seem reasonable in your case.

In `constrained-categories`, I called the class that encapsulates these methods [`Morphism`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:Morphism). (Which is quite a misnomer; regrettably, I chose the names rather poorly in a misguided effort to keep close compatibility with Haskell's standard classes and only hint at the mathematical names.) Your `PreCartesian` corresponds to my [`PreArrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:PreArrow).